# Spring @Transactional serializable does not work as expected

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I use `Spring Data JPA` with `Hibernate ORM`.

There is the common entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_entity_table")
public class SomeEntity {

   private @Id UUID uuid;
   private String userId;

   //getters and setters and constructors
}
```

**Common Service:**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EntityService {

  private final EntityRepository entityRepository;

  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
  public void get(String userId) {
    1. entityRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);
    2. SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity(UUID.randomUUID(), userId);
    3. entityRepository.save(someEntity);
    4. List<SomeEntity> allByUserId = entityRepository.findAllByUserId(userId);
  }
}
```

I set breakpoint in 2 line. Than I go to my database and insert row manually with the same `userId` and with the different `uuid`. I expected that hibernate before committing insert of entity, executes `select by userId` one more time and if count of rows changes *(like in my case)* exception should have been thrown. But hibernate only executes insert.

What I doing wrong?

P.S. `repeatable read` isolation works as I expected (Getting entity, changes in code, changes manually in database, save entity in code => exception thrown).

Comment: Do you use a database that actually supports that isolation level?

Comment: @M.Deinum i use optimistic lock, so spring should not use database locks for this case. I expect that spring check count of rows before insert

Comment: Spring doesn't check nor locks anything. Also using optimistic locking doesn't change anything. Again do you actually use a database that supports that isolation level, if not it then won't work (and will probably fallback to something else).

Comment: @M.Deinum but why `repeatable read` isolation works prefect? example:
1. get entity (hibernate calls `SELECT`)
2. change entity
3. save entity(hibernate calls `SELECT` and than `UPDATE`).
If you manually change this entity between 1 and 3, `LockAcquisitionException` will be thrown. And this isolation works in app layer, not in database. Hibernate checks that entity has been modified and throws exception.
Why there is no check for count rows in case of `serializable` isolation

Comment: Sigh . I give up. You apparently don't want to answer the questions. The fact that one isolation level works doesn't mean it supports other isolation levels. This has nothing to do with spring but with your database and how it supports transactions. You fail to understand that and I suggest you readup on how transactions and isolation levels work.

Comment: @M.Deinum if you use optimistic lock, it does not use locks on database. Locks on database layer uses with pessimistic locks. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KnockKnock I'm pretty sure you are. Optimistic locks can't be implemented on application level alone, their point is to make concurrent operations in database consistent.